# JAVA ¿Cómo convierto un resultado de una operación de Double a Int?

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
    switch(metodoDePago)
    {
        case "EFECTIVO": valorCondescuento = valorNeto * 0.90;
        break;
        
        case "CHEQUE": valorCondescuento = valorNeto * 0.95;
        break;
        
        case "TARJETA DE CREDITO": valorCondescuento = valorNeto * 0.92;
        break;
        
        case "TARJETA DE CRÉDITO": valorCondescuento = valorNeto * 0.92;  //EN CASO DE QUE ESCRIBA CON TILDE
        break;
    }
    return(valorCondescuento);
```

Lo que hace esto es que toma una variable de tipo int y la multiplica con un decimal, esto se guarda en una variable de tipo Double "valorConDescuento",

por lo tanto esto me devuelve un valor ejemplo: 61750.0 pero quiero que me devuelva 61.750 ósea que la coma se corra hacia la izquierda, esto sin cambiar el tipo de variables que tengo declaradas.

¿es posible?

Comment: Primero 61750.0 el separador no es una como es un punto, denotando punto decimal y no se aplican separador para los miles porque eso es semántica de lectura para el lenguaje de programación no es importante, y si quieres mostrar una coma debes aplicar un formato al momento de imprimir en consola debes utilizar DecimalFormat que pasaría el double a String con la separación.

Comment: No tiene sentido modificar el dato ahí. El formato es algo relativo, depende del contexto, puede que necesites a `valorCondescuento` en diferentes contextos: en uno con separador de miles, en otro sin separador, en otro con un prefijo de la moneda, etc. Puede que en otro contexto, luego del `return` necesites hacer alguna operación con el dato ... Por eso nunca conviene formatear valores numéricos donde se generan. Entonces, tienes que aplicar formato en el contexto donde recibes a `valorCondescuento`, así, este trozo de código será reutilizable para todos los contextos posibles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta añadir esto a todas las líneas en donde quieras el cambio.

```
case "EFECTIVO": valorCondescuento = (int)(valorNeto * 0.90);
```

Lo que hace es castear la variable a entero, por decirlo de una manera cambiar el tipo de la variable en esa línea.

[https://sites.google.com/site/pro012iessanandres/java/conversion-entre-tipos-primitivos-casting#:~:text=El%20casting%20es%20un%20procedimiento,relaci%C3%B3n%20de%20herencia%20entre%20ambas](https://sites.google.com/site/pro012iessanandres/java/conversion-entre-tipos-primitivos-casting#:%7E:text=El%20casting%20es%20un%20procedimiento,relaci%C3%B3n%20de%20herencia%20entre%20ambas). te dejo eso por si quieres buscar más

Comment: CARLOS, me dice que no es posible convertir double a string,

Comment: si me puedes adjuntar como te quedó el código

Comment: Disculpa había entendido mal lo que necesitabas, mira la respuesta de nuevo ya lo corregí

Comment: te agradecería si te sirvió que le des a la palomita que sale en medio de las flechas de mi pregunta. me serviría mucho gracias.